# Undefined Apache server error rdbmmap

Tags: apache, server

Since few days I've got the following error message in my Server error log :

> www.xxx.com [client XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX] rdbmmap (21): rdbm_fetch failed (1)

Although the site is loading right. I would like to know about this error. Can't find anything around. Does anybody know about this?

**Server configuration :**

Server-Info: Apache/2.2.31 (Unix)
PHP-Version: 7.1.8
WordPress: 4.8.1
MySQL-Version: 5.6.37

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you using strato hosting?

Comment: Yes. Hosted by Strato.

Comment: I think is some sort of anti spam protection system. Contact your hositing and ask for.

Answer (score 0):

Please have a look at this: [Map Reduce & RDBMS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33448268/map-reduce-rdbms)

RDBMS - stands for Remote database management system,
Client- is the browser,oder crawler bot ,that send the Request.
Fetch Failed-  means, the system could fetch the request to the database.